# Can I use my Mac to play music stores on an old iPod shuffle?

Tags: itunes, ipod-shuffle

I want to plug my very old iPod shuffle it into my more current Mac and play from my shuffle's play list.  Can I do that and if so how?

I can see all the songs in "My Music" but cant play it.

Comment: It helps if you identify which models of what devices you have.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly easy.

1. Simply select your iPod in the iTunes sidebar
2. Check the Manually manage music and videos box under "Options" (in the "Summary" screen).
3. Now you should be able to play your music from your iPod shuffle

Comment: I don't know if it works both directions or not, but I do know that new devices won't connect with older versions of iTunes. But, as I said, not sure if that goes both directions (such as an older device connecting to a newer version of iTunes).

Comment: According to [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204095), iTunes should recognize every iPod even older ones.